# Deleted Distribution Certificate

Tags: ios4, app-store, distribution, app-store-connect

I had to delete my distribution certificate and make a new one. I am wondering if I will be able to submit updates for apps already on app store. The distribution profiles I have used to submit them are "invalid" now. Will I still be able to submit updates with a different distribution profile?

Answer (score 0):

If you create the distribution profile form the same developer account, then yes. 
A similar thing will happen when the year of subscription is over, you renew he contract with Apple and then re-generate the certificates that have expired since.